# Bilinear interpolation of a matrix to extract Z at different locations [R]

Tags: coordinate-system, r, interpolation, geoid

I have that geoid heights (quasi-geoid model hBG18) in a form that matrix :

```
library(tidyverse)
Geo <- read.table("https://www.isgeoid.polimi.it/Geoid/Europe/Belgium/public/hBG18.dat", 
           header=FALSE)
Geo <- Geo %>% rename("x" = "V2", "y" = "V1","z" = "V3")
```

And  I would like to extract that heights for the given locations:

```
newdata <- structure(list(x = c(5.6029075, 5.60290583333333, 5.60290283333333, 
5.60289525, 5.60289583333333, 5.60289016666667), y = c(49.7203561666667, 
49.7203568333333, 49.7203568333333, 49.7203585, 49.7203595, 49.7203593333333
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried to use `interp.surface()` from the package 'fields' but it does not work.

```
newdata$z <- fields::interp.surface(Geoide, newdata)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I was wondering how could I proceed to obtain that Z value.

I have also tried to do an interpolation of the Geoid heights with `interp()` form the package "akima", to after extract the Z value. But the code does not work either...

**EDIT**

[More information about the quasi-geoid model used](https://www.isgeoid.polimi.it/Geoid/Europe/Belgium/belgium2018_g.html)

Comment: What's `Geoide`? Have you tried to convert the dataframe from the file to a list as described in the documentation for `interp.surface`? If that's gone wrong then that could be the reason for the error. Edit the Q to show how you made `Geoide`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data - I had to download the data separately because the site has an invalid certificate. Also there's no need to pull in the tidyverse to rename some columns:

```
> Geo <- read.table("hBG18.dat", header=FALSE)
> names(Geo)=c("y","x","z")
```

Now convert to a list structure. I'm not sure if this is the right way round, I should take more care with my X and Y coordinates, but its irrelevant at this point. If this data doesn't look like you expect then transpose it or something.

```
> d = list(x=unique(Geo$x), y=unique(Geo$y), z=matrix(Geo$z, 401,401))
> image(d)
```

[image]

x-y of `newdata` overlays x-y of `d`:

```
> newdata
         x        y
1 5.602907 49.72036
2 5.602906 49.72036
3 5.602903 49.72036
4 5.602895 49.72036
5 5.602896 49.72036
6 5.602890 49.72036
```

And we can interpolate:

```
> interp.surface(d, newdata)
[1] 45.19709 45.19709 45.19709 45.19708 45.19708 45.19708
```

This is a bit slapdash but I'm busy, but basically you need to reshape your data frame into a 401 x 401 matrix in the right order with a vector of X and Y coordinates, both of length 401.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use terra::extract with "method=bilinear"

Your example data

```
Geo <- read.table("https://www.isgeoid.polimi.it/Geoid/Europe/Belgium/public/hBG18.dat", header=FALSE)
colnames(Geo) <- c("y", "x", "z")
pts <- data.frame(x = c(5.6029075, 5.60290583333333, 5.60290283333333, 
5.60289525, 5.60289583333333, 5.60289016666667), y = c(49.7203561666667, 
49.7203568333333, 49.7203568333333, 49.7203585, 49.7203595, 49.7203593333333
))
```

Solution

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(Geo[, c(2,1,3)], type="xyz")
e <- extract(x, pts, method="bilinear")
e
#  ID      z
#1  1 45.19709
#2  2 45.19709
#3  3 45.19709
#4  4 45.19708
#5  5 45.19708
#6  6 45.19708
```